# Why do I keep getting a ValueError: math domain error in Python?

Tags: python, math, quadratic

So I was making a quadradic equation solver in Python and when the calculation was happening, an error came up and I'm not sure what is happening.

```
from math import sqrt

a = float(input("a: "))
b = float(input("b: "))
c = float(input("c: "))
Z = (b * b) - (4 * a * c)

x1 = ((-b) + float(sqrt(Z))) / (2 * a)
x2 = ((-b) - float(sqrt(Z))) / (2 * a)

print("x = " + str(x1))
print("x = " + str(x2))
```

This is the code.

Comment: is it possible that `Z` is negative? You should get the square root of the absolute value, no? `sqrt(abs(Z))`

Comment: Taking the square root of the absolute value isn't a good idea: it would result in printing incorrect answers for quadratic equations that don't have any real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because if `(4 * a * c)` >  `(b * b)`, Z becomes negative and square root of a negative number results in an imaginary number. `math.sqrt()` doesn't take negative parameters.
Edit: As @jakub said so, you can try getting the absolute value's square root.